# Set default location after cflogin

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8, cflogin

I have a couple web applications written in ColdFusion.  The applications have their own folder inside the CF root folder.  When I do a successful `<cflogin>` I am returned to the index page of the root folder.  I want the user to stay within that apps folder   I know it can be done, I just can't remember how to start.  Something where you set the root page for the application withing that App's `Application.cfc` page.  Any insight?

Comment: Do you have an index.cfm in the application's root folder?

Comment: yes. There is an index.cfm in the root.

Comment: What happens upon successful log in is handled by the code within the `<cflogin>` tags. Most likely that is located within your `Application.cfc` file.  Can you share that code snippet so we can help you?

Comment: I figured it out.  Had some hidden Application.cfc's throughout the App lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete an Application.cfc from your local drive, that doesn't mean it was deleted from the server.  So you might have some hidden Application.cfc's thoughout the App.